# jQuery XMLHttpRequest start and end

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

We can use the followings to trigger an even when the ajax calls are started or completed:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
   // an event
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  // another event
});
```

However, after some testings I realized the above listeners dont capture the calls via XMLHttpRequest.

Any other way around?
Thanks,

Comment: use `ajax` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Of course they don't, `XMLHttpRequest` isn't jQuery

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, but how to resolve it?